# Automatically upgrade old, deprecated selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, deprecated

I have a jQuery file that works with the version 1.3.2 but when I change the version with the 1.9.1 the jQuery file stops working.I know that there may be selectors that are deprecated but the jQuery file is too large to manually check and replace them.

I was wondering if exists any program or plugin to automatically replace old deprecated selectors with new ones.

Thanks !

This is my [jQuery file](http://www.menu.hol.es/prettySociable_uncompressed_1.2.1/js/jquery.prettySociable.js)

Comment: The obvious solution would be to just visit [***the plugins Github page***](https://github.com/scaron/prettySociable) and download the latest version, and not ask us to rewrite a plugin that someone else is developing ?

Comment: adeneo i don't ask anyone to rewrite any plugin,the Jquery file that I have doesn't work with the latest version so I was wondering if exists any plugin to automatically replace old selectors with new ones.

Comment: But the file you're linking to where it says "This is my jQuery file" is just a plugin, and that plugin has since been updated, so why would you need to update selectors. jQuery uses Sizzle for the selectors, and there's been no major changes to that ?

Comment: I'll try to use m_gol solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're using `jQuery.browser`, which was removed as it's a bad practice to use browser-sniffing.

The good news is jQuery has issued the Migrate plugin to ease upgrading. Download it from http://jquery.com/download and you can upgrade to jQuery 1.10.2; just include the migrate plugin after jQuery but before your code. The Migrate plugin restores some old behavior, like `jQuery.browser` but prints warnings to the console so that it's easy to see what needs to be changed to get full compatibility with the new version. When you get rid of all the warnings, you can remove the Migrate plugin and work with a pure jQuery 1.10.2.

Comment: I just search into my site but it seems that the migrate plugin is already there.The only error i het is .prettySociable is undefined

Comment: @user2900555 I see you've accepted my answer - does it mean it worked?

Comment: If you still see an error, please post a full error you get with the stacktrace included. It's hard to say what can be wrong.

Comment: @user2900555 BTW, the first plugin line, `$.prettySociable = {version: 1.21};`, doesn't make sense since you're overwriting it in the very next line.

Comment: Now i use the 1.8.4 version for my plugin and is working great.